# Set mocked Eloquent model public attributes

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, phpunit

I have a model Model1 that has many Model2.

An instance of Model1 is passsed as a paramer to the fuction that I want to test. the function that I would like to test looks like this:

```
function funnctionTotest(Model1 $moel1)
{
   foreach($moel1->model2s as $model2) {
     ....
   }
}
```

The example below does not work. I am putting it here as a starting point for a real solution (array() should be replaced by something else maybe a collections of Model2 instances).

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Model1')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
$mock->setAttribute('Model2s', array());
```

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do here. What does `setAttribute(string, array)` do, and what are you trying to do with it? If you mock Model1 without telling it which methods to stub, then all of its methods, including `setAttribute`, will be stubbed, so `setAttribute` doesn't do anything at all. If you really need to use `setAttribute`, you might want to consider not mocking Model1 at all and just instantiating it as normal.

Comment: @Ataraxia, hope it is cleared now after my edits

Comment: Somewhat, but is there a reason you're mocking Model1 instead of just instantiating it normally? Again, if you mock it without setting any methods as you did in your example, your calling setAttribute won't do anything. Can you be a bit more specific about what you mean when you say it "doesn't work"? What's happening, and what are you hoping to get it to do? Just want to be sure I understand the problem fully before submitting an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that works perfectly for me:

```
$campaignMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Model2')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(array('setAttribute', 'getAttribute'))
    ->getMock();
$model2 = new Model2();
$model2->someprop = 'somevalue';
$campaignMock->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method('getAttribute')
    ->with('model2s')
    ->willReturn(array($model2));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$mock->setAttribute('Model2s', array());
```

Won't do anything because in PHPUnit, by default, all mocked objects' methods are stubbed out, meaning they do nothing and return `NULL`. You could avoid this by doing one of two things:

1. Set a list of methods to stub out in the mock builder. Any methods not specified in this list retain their default functionality.

   ```
   $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Model1')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(array('doSomeStuff', 'doSomeOtherStuff'))
    ->getMock();
   $mock->setAttribute('Model2s', array());
   ```
2. Don't mock Model1 at all--just instantiate it as a normal instance of Model1.

   ```
    $model1 = new Model1();
    $model1->setAttrbute('Model2s', array());
   ```

If there are no methods that need to be stubbed in Model1 in order for your test case to run, option #2 makes the most sense.